# На выходе нужно получить многомерный массив, где каждый вложенный массив состоит из цифр, в сумме дающих значение константы

Tags: javascript, массивы, константа

имеется значение константы = 10
и имеется массив значений = [1, 2, 5, 10, 9, 8, 6, 4]
нужно упорядочить массив значений так чтобы он не превышал значение константы
например
значение константы = 10
массив должен упорядочиться в
(5 4 1)
(10)
(9 1)
(6 4)
(8 2)
мне просто дана константа и массив и я не знаю какую функцию либо цикл нужно писать

Comment: Нужно писать функцию решения проблемы "Subset sum"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как у вас смог массив отсортироваться в `(5 4 1) (10) (9 1) (6 4) (8 2)`, когда `4` в массиве только одна

ну попробуйте сначала отсортировать массив по возрастанию, а затем набирать суммы от старших и младших элементов двигаясь к центру

или вам надо из массива собрать все варианты сумм, равные константе?

тогда отсортируйте массив и сделайте рекурсивную функцию, которая вычисляет сумму текущего элемента массива с результатом рекурсивной функции от последующих элементов

типа

```
function mysum(sum, pos, arr, value) {
    // если сумма уже превышает заданное значение - прекращаем поиск на данной глубине рекурсии
    if (sum > value)
        return;

    // ищем суммы на данной глубине рекурсии
    for (index = pos; index < arr.length; index++) {
        new_sum = sum + arr[pos];
        if (new_sum == value) {
            // искомый вариант
        }

        mysum(new_sum, pos + 1, arr, 10);
    }
}

mysum(0, 0, arr, 10)
```

Comment: да все варианты сумм

Comment: @Саид, а сразу так написать нельзя было? :)

Comment: @Саид, тогда, как писали выше, вам нужен `Subset sum`.

Comment: @Zhihar можно ли решить это через цикл while? если да то каким образом?

Comment: @Саид, рекурсивные вызовы можно развернуть через `while`, но зачастую это очень извратные решения, по сути вам надо сэмитировать вызов функции заменив его на `while`, если вам обязательно `while` нужен в программе - то замените `for` на `while` просто, а рекурсию не трогайте